# Select longest working employee in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My database looks like:

**Table: dept_emp**:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| emp_no (Employee Number) | from_date (Hire date) | to_date (Worked up to) |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                        5 | 1995-02-27            | 2001-01-19             |
|                      500 | 1968-01-01            | 9999-01-01             |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Note: If the employee is still currently working for the company their to_date will show `9999-01-01`.

What I'm wanting to do is display the emp_no of the longest working employee. I'm not sure how to do that with the random `9999-01-01`'s in the database.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT emp_no 
  FROM (SELECT max(datediff( (SELECT to_date 
                                FROM dept_emp), 
                             (SELECT from_date 
                                FROM dept_emp)
                           )
                  )
       );
```

This doesn't work, and it also doesn't the take `9999-01-01` into account.

I'm thinking I should use `CURDATE()` in their some where?

Comment: What is your RDBMs? You tagged mysql and sqlserver

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hey, sorry I'm using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select 
  d.*,
  datediff(
    case when to_date = '9999-01-01' then current_date else to_date end,
    from_date) as how_long
from dept_emp d
where 
datediff(
    case when to_date = '9999-01-01' then current_date else to_date end,
    from_date) = (

  -- find the longest tenure
  select max(datediff(
    case when to_date = '9999-01-01' then current_date else to_date end,
    from_date))
  from dept_emp

)
```

If this is the kind of information you have in your table:

```
create table dept_emp (
  emp_no int,
  from_date date,
  to_date date
);
insert into dept_emp values 
(1, '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'),
(2, '2000-01-01', '2005-02-01'),
(3, '2000-01-01', '9999-01-01');
```

Your result will be:

```
| emp_no |                 from_date |                   to_date | how_long |
|--------|---------------------------|---------------------------|----------|
|      3 | January, 01 2000 00:00:00 | January, 01 9999 00:00:00 |     5902 |
```

Example SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55886/11

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest to make that to_date DEFAULT NULL.
You want to have NULL there, if employee is still working, no need for 9999- stuff.

Now, to your question about longest working employee. You could calculate the date difference like this, accounting for NULL to be today's date:

```
SELECT emp_no, MAX(DATEDIFF( IFNULL(to_date,CURDATE()) ,from_date)) FROM dept_emp;
```

Here what we did, is if to_date is NULL, meaning person is still employed, we assume his to_date is today's date which is true.

**EDIT:** I am sorry, forgot to return the employee number, just add your emp_no to the query.

**EDIT 2:** Since you are not allowed to use NULL, this is what you should do:

```
  SELECT emp_no, MAX(DATEDIFF( IF(to_date='9999-01-01',CURDATE(), to_date) ,from_date)) FROM dept_emp;
```

So basically, we are saying if 9999- is set, use it as todays date. Hope this helps.  I assume that no one's to_date is not going to be bigger that today's date, other than 9999- of course.

**EDIT 3:** You are right about emp_no, so here it goes:

```
SELECT emp_no, DATEDIFF( IF(to_date='9999-01-01',CURDATE(), to_date) 
,from_date) as longest_date FROM dept_emp ORDER BY longest_date DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Where you are returning the employee number? As it is what the OP wants?

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the 9999-01-01? I can't be messing with the dates.

Comment: @LearningProcess if you still want to use 9999-its fine, just use: SELECT emp_no, MAX(DATEDIFF( to_date ,from_date)) FROM dept_emp; .. By incorporating NULL, I actually made query a bit more complex, but overall design better.

Comment: @Muhammed M. This is definitely helping, thanks so much! Let's take this for example, say:      emp_no = 500, from_date=1968-01-01, to_date=2016-01-05 ......... AND emp_no = 650, from_date=1970-01-01, to_date=9999-01-01.     Technically, the employee with the emp_no as 500 should the longest, but with your method the emp_no 650 is the longest because its getting the difference between 1970-01-01 and 9999-01-01 which is larger than the current date. The NULL thing is definitely the way to go, but I cant do that here. Is there anyway I make an "if statement" for if the date = 9999-01-01 be CURDA

Comment: Oh, ok now I see your problem. Let me rewrite my answer, give me a sec.

Comment: Its gives me the correct max time someone has been working there, but it doesn't display the correct emp_no, it's actually displaying the first emp_no in the database. Thanks for all your help, someone else has actually answered my question.

Comment: @LearningProcess you are right about emp_no, I modified answer to show exactly what u need.

Comment: @MuhammedM. Much better, the only issue from this one is that it's only outputting one of the emp_no's whose date is the longest. There's actually multiple employees who should be displayed because they have the same longest_date.

Comment: @LearningProcess you adjust that LIMIT 0,10 -> or whatever you need, it will give you that many employees. Cheers. Or you can remove Limit altogether. I though you needed 1 employee only. The answer you accepted actually uses two SELECT statements, so be careful with that ;) My is a more precise answer.

Comment: @MuhammedM. Awesome, thanks for all the help again man, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the longest-tenured worker who is still employed (i.e., their `to_date = '9999-01-01'`), then this should work:

```
select emp_no 
from dept_emp 
where to_date = '9999-01-01' and 
datediff(to_date, from_date) = 
( 
   select max(datediff(to_date, from_date)) 
   from dept_emp where to_date = '9999-01-01'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the employee id that has worked the longest. Note the CTE is not necessary its purely for readability. See second query if you are going for performance. You can solve the '9999-01-01' max date issue by using a Case statement like so.

With CTE:

```
;with cte_stage as (
    select emp_no
    ,case when to_date = '9999-01-01' 
         then DateDiff(DAY,from_date,GETDATE()) 
         else DATEDIFF(DAY,from_date,to_date) END as 'age'
     from dept_emp
)
select emp_no
from cte_stage
where age = ( select max(age) from cte_stage)
```

Without CTE:

```
select emp_no
from dept_emp
where case 
    when to_date = '9999-01-01' 
    then DateDiff(DAY,from_date,GETDATE()) 
    else DATEDIFF(DAY,from_date,to_date) END  = 
    ( 
         select max( 
              case 
                   when to_date = '9999-01-01' 
                   then DateDiff(DAY,from_date,GETDATE()) 
                   else DATEDIFF(DAY,from_date,to_date) 
               END 
          ) 
    from dept_emp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of employees is not large, there is a simple solution:

```
SELECT
  *, datediff(to_date, from_date) AS duration
FROM (
  SELECT
    emp_no, from_date, IF(to_date <> '9999-01-01', to_date, CURRENT_DATE) AS to_date
  FROM
    dept_emp
) AS tmp
ORDER BY duration DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This uses a subselect to replace the `'9999-01-01'` value with the `CURRENT_DATE`, then, it orders results by duration, and get the first employee.
Again, this is efficient enough if the number of rows in the table is not too large.

---

> Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c2b7/7/0).
>
> Sample data:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO dept_emp VALUES
> (500, '1968-01-01', '2016-01-05'),
> (650, '1970-01-01', '9999-01-01'),
> (700, '2006-01-01', '2016-01-01');
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> | emp_no |                 from_date |                   to_date | duration |
> |--------|---------------------------|---------------------------|----------|
> |    500 | January, 01 1968 00:00:00 | January, 05 2016 00:00:00 |    17536 |
> ```

---

And here is official MySQL documentation on control flow functions:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html